# How do I create a distribution group of a range of numbers by a given number of groups

Tags: javascript, arrays, frequency-distribution

In Javascript, 
if I have a range of numbers, say 0-10000.
like this:

```
var min = 0;
var max = 10000;
```

and I want to split this range into a number of buckets by a input:

```
var buckets = 5;
```

in this case, I want to return an array of numbers that splits up this range:
ie. the resulting numbers would be: 0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000

if I said 10 buckets, the numbers would be 0, 1000, 2000, etc....

My issue is if I have 8 buckets, 12 buckets 32 buckets....
How would I do this in javascript?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dif = max - min;
var a = dif/bucked;

for (var i=min; i<=max;i=i+a){
  i;
}
```

Comment: I forgot the array, but that should not be a Problem for you :-)

Comment: yeah, I figured that one out.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem, more such questions please :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but also needed to create a string literal to describe each bucket, like a 'from-to' string. Altering Seva Arkhangelskiy's answer, this is the function I came up with. It returns the limit range for each bucket, but also a proper name for the bucket.

```
function distribute (max, buckets) {
    var arr = [], rpt = max / buckets, groupLiteral_low;
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i += rpt) {
        if (Math.ceil(i) != i || i==0) {
            groupLiteral_low = Math.ceil(i);
        } else {
            groupLiteral_low = Math.ceil(i)+1;
        }
        arr.push({
            "limit": (Math.floor(rpt+i)),
            "literal": groupLiteral_low + "-" + (Math.floor(rpt+i))
        });
    }
    return arr; 
}
```

For example, `distribute(100,3)` will return 
​

```
0: Object { limit: 33, literal: "0-33" }​
1: Object { limit: 66, literal: "34-66" }​
2: Object { limit: 100, literal: "67-100" }
```

Comment: How could something like this work for values below zero? Say you had a range from -10 to 10 and wanted 4 buckets like... "-10 to -5",  "-4 to 0", "1 to 5", "6 to 10" - Also, note that here we would just swap out the "-" seperator for the word "to".

Answer (score 1):

```
var min = 0,
    max = 1000,
    buckets = 8,
    i, array = [];

for (i = min; i <= max; i += (max - min) / buckets) {
    array.push(i);
}
```

Comment: missed you by a half of a second.  Just added the array thing also. Thanks again.